# Disable/Enable Input Text conditionally in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am building a table in LWC and the table iterates on a list coming from apex. There is a custom object called Budget AOP which i query and put the data in a list and iterate it to bring a table. Now while i bring this from Apex i have to also bring the total values, which is summing up the number fields and showing a total value.

Problem- I have a edit button, on click of which i enable/disable the input text fields so that user can put the new value and i have a save button on click of which i call apex and save the data. Problem comes when user also gets a enable text field for Total value.

What i want is i don't want the Total value rows to be enabled even if user clicks on edit button . But this value is also coming from the list which i am iterating in the for loop.

```
<template for:each={budgetData} for:item="budget"> 
  <div class="slds-truncate" >
    <lightning-input type="text"  id= {budget.Id} onchange={onchangevalues}  name="upselling" value={budget.Upselling_Investment__c} disabled={disableFieldBudget}  >
    </lightning-input>
  </div>
 </template>
```

On click of edit i simply make disableFieldBudget= false, but then also the total value rows becomes enabled in that case. Any Suggestion

Comment: can you add more code snippet? Specially of table/row and JS

Comment: Pre-process budget data and determine editability OR make a subcomponent that can work this out.